# Reading chess.com player games data into spark dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I used the chess.com API to collect games data of a player. The API gives a JSON response and I saved this JSON response as a CSV file.

Code to save the game data in a CSV file format:

```
data-url= https://api.chess.com/pub/player/erik/games
games= requests.get(data-url).json()
df= pd.json_normalize(games['games'])
df['poi']= 'erik'
df.to_csv('data.csv', index=False)
```

Now if I read this file into a pandas dataframe, it works. However, when I read this same file into a spark dataframe, all my data is in the first column and all the other columns are None.

How do i fix this? Any relevant suggestions are much appreciated.

Spark Read file into spark data frame code:

```
df = spark.read.format("csv").load(
r'/media/disk2/isb_ras/sachin/chess/matches/games_larrygm.csv',header=True)
```

**Update:**

I realized that the issue is caused by the data in the PGN field of the data file. I read the data file into a pandas data frame, dropped the pgn feature, and saved it to a new file. Then I read the new file into a Spark data frame and it worked.

Sample PGN Data when I print the first value from the pandas' data frame:

```
'[Event "Live Chess"]\n[Site "Chess.com"]\n[Date "2011.12.01"]\n[Round "-"]\n[White "-KingOfTheCastle-"]\n[Black "lambruskice"]\n[Result "1-0"]\n[CurrentPosition "rnbq1bnr/pp1p2p1/4kp2/2pQ1N1B/4P3/8/PPP2PPP/RNB1K2R b KQ -"]\n[Timezone "UTC"]\n[ECO "C40"]\n[ECOUrl "https://www.chess.com/openings/Kings-Pawn-Opening-Kings-Knight-Damiano-Defense"]\n[UTCDate "2011.12.01"]\n[UTCTime "19:07:25"]\n[WhiteElo "1350"]\n[BlackElo "1153"]\n[TimeControl "600"]\n[Termination "-KingOfTheCastle- won by checkmate"]\n[StartTime "19:07:25"]\n[EndDate "2011.12.01"]\n[EndTime "19:08:34"]\n[Link "https://www.chess.com/game/live/213529090"]\n\n1. e4 {[%clk 0:10:00]} 1... e5 {[%clk 0:10:00]} 2. Nf3 {[%clk 0:09:57.9]} 2... f6 {[%clk 0:09:58]} 3. d4 {[%clk 0:09:49.8]} 3... exd4 {[%clk 0:09:55.9]} 4. Nxd4 {[%clk 0:09:48.4]} 4... h5 {[%clk 0:09:52.6]} 5. Be2 {[%clk 0:09:44.8]} 5... c5 {[%clk 0:09:42.1]} 6. Bxh5+ {[%clk 0:09:39.4]} 6... Ke7 {[%clk 0:09:32.4]} 7. Nf5+ {[%clk 0:09:36.1]} 7... Ke6 {[%clk 0:09:25.6]} 8. Qd5# {[%clk 0:09:29.5]} 1-0\n'
```

there are a lot of special characters in this pgn info. But there are no commas. Now how can I read this file into a spark data frame by ensuring the PGN is considered as one single enrty of the pgn column.

Comment: Didn't you just ask this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67375727/reading-chess-com-player-games-data-into-spark-dataframe-not-functioning

Comment: Use spark.read.option("delimiter", "\t").csv(file) or sep instead of delimiter.

Comment: @user12345, I tried sep='\t'. It didn't work. The file is definitely comma separated. If i read the same file in pandas, it works. Why is it not able to read the file properly into the spark data frame is something I don't understand.

Comment: @Wodford yep, I had 2 accounts one i had since college, and I created another one to track only the problems and solutions during work. I wanted that post to reach more people and I upvoted it with my old account. Moderates flagged it and that account is not active anymore. :(

Comment: @sachinkumars if it is comma separated then did you try `("delimiter", ",")`

Comment: yes i did, it didnt work. to help y'all have the data, i have added a minimum reproducible code of getting and storing the data. Please let me know what works in this case. It is clearing being affected by the data in 'pgn' column